# Passing axios.get URLs into axios.all based on options

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, promise, axios

I am building a vue app that will search YouTube channels based on which options are selected.

When the option is TRUE, I push that string into an array which holds the URLs of the axios.get() requests.

I am looping through that array and running axios.get() and returning the value. I am getting a response under Promise{} with and object inside [[PromiseValue]].

At the end I am combining the responses into a vue data element(catAndDogResults) but I am getting an undefined in the end.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

```
data () {
  return {
    catVideos: true,
    dogVideos: true,
    catResults: [],
    dogResults: [],
    catAndDogResults: []
  }
},
methods: 
  search: function() {
  var that = this
  var cats =  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=cats'
  var dogs =  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=dogs'
  var urls = []

  if (this.catVideos == true) {
    urls.push(cats)
  }

  if (this.dogVideos == true) {
    urls.push(dogs)
  }

  function getVideos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      console.log(axios.get(urls[i])) // returns under [[PromiseValue]]:object
        return axios.get(urls[i])
    }
  }

  axios.all([
    getVideos()
  ])
  .then(axios.spread(function (catRes, dogRes) {
    that.catResults = catRes.data.items
    that.dogResults = dogRes.data.items
    that.catAndDogResults = that.catResults.concat(that.dogResults)
  }))
}
```

***EDITS***

Fixed spelling mistakes

Comment: Please, don't forget to select the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your `getVideos()` method to return the array *after* the for loop:

```
function getVideos() {
    var requests = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        requests.push(axios.get(urls[i]));
    }
    return requests;
}
```

And then, call it like that:

```
axios.all(getVideos())
     .then(function (catRes, dogRes) { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @tiagodws should fix the issue. I just wanted to rewrite the `getVideos` function, you could write it using ES6 syntax like the following:

```
var getVideos = () =>  urls.map(url => axios.get(url))
```